# What is this second number after HTTP status code?

Tags: http, http-status-code-404

I did grep " 500 " on the request log and got this, I understand that HTTP code is 200 but what is this 501?

`POST /api/v1/url HTTP/1.1" 200 501`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your server is Apache and logs are in [CLF](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/logs.html) (Common Log Format).
Then 501 is the size of the server response (in bytes and in total).

Comment: @AdityaVerma No it is not. It is distributed under Apache Licence, but the code as nothing to do with Apache server. Whatever, standard logs are commonly of the same format for many servers.